# Ado net source fail to acquire connection

Tags: ssis, azure-sql-database, ado.net

I have a SSIS package package that connects with azure sql database through using ADO net connection manager with SQLclient data provider. Authentication method used is Integrated security. The SSIs package executes fine through Visual studio 2019. However when executed through Autosys it fails. The error in log file says **Ado net source fails to acquire connection with error message : one or more error occurred.**
The job machine have .net 8 and .net framework 4.8. I searched over internet to find out that SqlClient data provider comes by default in .net framework. System requirements seems to be fine to me. What could be the reason

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I was told that the error "failed to acquire connection" occurs when there is incompatibility with drivers. The SqlClient data provider comes by default with .net framework. I have added .net framework to the computer that runs the job. Still the jobs fails and error is same. I am not sure how to resolve this issue.